# Give user access to function in different schema

Tags: oracle, function, schema, sql-grant

I'm having the following problem:
My main schema (db_main) has a certain function f_docrazymaths() as number and I need to give access to this function to another user called db_read.

I know that I can grant access to tables and views, but how do I grant access to functions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `grant execute on  f_docrazymaths to db_read`.

Comment: Yes, the answer did help!

Answer (score 1):

With relations (`TABLE` or `VIEW`) you grant access for `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, etc.

For a function or procedure, you grant `EXECUTE` rights.

For a sequence generator, you grant `USAGE`

Note that the function will either have the security of the definer or the invoker.  If it is the invoker, then the user also needs access to underlying tables, views, and sequence generators.